# How to auto comment on SASS selectors using Sublime 3?

Tags: sass, emmet

For a while now, I'm coding SASS/compass on Sublime 3 with the following pattern:

```
.selector{
  property:value;
  property:value;
  property:value;
  >.sub-selector{
    property:value;
    property:value;
  }//>.sub-selector
}//.selector
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Sublime (or Emmet) after typing the selector?

---

FYI: I already used a snippet where I type "." or "#" and hit tab and it duplicated the text pointer after the braces, but it wasn't very productive.

Comment: Do you mean `cmd + /` ?

Comment: @JoshSpears - I think he or she means that they want the closing squiggle bracket to be automatically appended with a comment stating what selector the closing block was targeting, like in their example.

Comment: Please post the code of the snippet you have tried and the output you get by using it.

Comment: I deleted the code, also it's irrelevant, i just don't want answers containing something similar. It was something like this: I typed `.` then `Tab` and the snippet would create the brackets and duplicate the text pointer to a comment after the closing bracket. So when you type anything would go to the selector and comment at the same time.

Comment: Well according to Emmet's docs, this kind of functionality does exist but for HTML code.